# Dagger2 injecting issue in the main activity when using retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, dagger

I am facing an issue when injecting the retrofit service object using dagger2. Here is the details of my scenario:

**Retrofit WebService Class:**

```
public interface WebService {                                                               
    Observable<Name> searchName(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

**Here is SubModule class:**

```
@Module
public class SetupModule {

    @Provides
   MainActivity provideWebService(WebService webService) {
        return new MainActivity(webService);
    }
}
```

**Here is SubComponent class:**

```
@SetupScope
@Subcomponent(modules = SubModule.class)
public interface SubComponent {
    MainActivity inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**Here is AppComponent Class:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
        NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{
    SubComponent plus(SubModule subModule);
}
```

**Here is the component creation in BaseApplication Class:**

```
 public SubComponent createSubComponent()
    {
        subComponent = appComponent.plus(new subModule());
        return subComponent;
    }
```

**Here is the MainActivity class:**

```
 public MainActivity(WebService webService) {
        this.webService = webService;
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
((BaseApplication) getApplication()).createSubComponent().inject(this);
}
```

I am getting the `webservice nullpointerexception` when trying to access the searchName method in WebService interface from MainActivity.

Please help me to find out why webservice object getting null?

Comment: constructor injection is not possible for activities and fragments in android. You will have to give with field injection

Comment: Can you please hints how can i do that in this scenario?

Comment: refer to any guide on dagger 2, this is basic dagger stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think, at first you should remove WebService from activity constructor, and initiate service something like that:

```
@Inject
WebService webService;
```

Comment: Seems like its working. But why i need to remove the webservice from activity constructor. As i am providing the dependency via the SubModule activity constructor.